# How to calculate the difference between multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Users**

```
 Id Name
---------------------
1   Robert Baratheon
2   Cercei Lanister
3   Jon snow
```

**Transactions**

```
Id  UserId   Date     Amount    NewBalance   NewTotal
---------------------------------------------------------
1   1      2020/03/21   100        100         100
2   1      2020/04/06   100        200         200
3   1      2020/04/07   25         225         225
4   2      2020/03/03   100        100         100
5   2      2020/04/07   30         130         130
6   3      2020/04/06   250        250        250
```

The `newBalance` is the sum of all amounts to this date and the `newTotal` is the sum of all positives amounts to this date.

**I want to order who has made the most money this week**

**Result Desired :**

```
UserId   UserName     Amount_made_this_week
---------------------------------------------
1   3      Jon snow           250
2   1      Robert Baratheon   125
3   2      Cercei Lanister    30
```

How do I write that in SQL?

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Getting the week from a date? Aggregating rows in order to get their sum? Something else?

Comment: Define "this week". Today plus the last six days, because a week has seven days?  Today plus the last two days, because today is Wednesday and a week starts with Monday for you?

Comment: a week is from last sunday to now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum up your `amount` filtering for this week and order the results:

```
SELECT Transactions.UserId, Users.Name, Sum(Transactions.Amount) as amount_made_this_week
FROM Transactions
    INNER JOIN Users
        ON Transactions.UserID = Users.ID
WHERE Transactions.Date BETWEEN #04/05/2020# AND #04/11/2020#
GROUP BY Userid, Name
ORDER BY amount_made_this_week DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can put your date range independent of bind variables, always setting the period of one week like:

```
SELECT T.UserId, U.Name, Sum(T.Amount) as Amount_made_this_week
FROM Transactions T
    INNER JOIN Users U
       ON T.UserID = U.ID 
WHERE T.Date > (SYSDATE-7)
GROUP BY Userid, Name
ORDER BY Amount_made_this_week DESC;
```

Comment: Is this for SQL Server? Looks like Oracle to me.